# Tibco jms with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, tibco, ems

I’m working on spring boot with tibco ems project.

Required to create producer nd consumer configurations. Could any one guide with configurations

Answer (score 4):

Import tibjms.jar library, then:

```
import com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory;
```

and create the following beans:

```
  @Bean
  public TibjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
      TibjmsConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:7222");
    return connectionFactory;
  }

  @Bean
  public JmsTemplate JmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate =
        new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
    return jmsTemplate;
  }
```

The receiver will be:

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    @JmsListener(destination = "test_queue")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
    }
}
```

and the sender will be:

```
JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("test_queue", "Hello");
```